# Checking whether $\sqrt{2}$ is contained in the ideal $(2,\sqrt{-5}+1)$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, ideals

Let $L=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-5},\sqrt{2})$ and $I=(2,\sqrt{-5}+1)$ the ideal in $\mathcal{O}_L$, the ring of algebraic integers in $L$, which is generated by $2$ and $\sqrt{-5}+1$

I want to show that $I=(\sqrt{2})$. Once I can show that $\sqrt{2}\in I$, this is easy.
But I don't know how to show that $\sqrt{2}$ is contained in $I$.
Every element in $I$ must be of the form $2a+(\sqrt{-5}+1)b$ for some $a,b\in \mathcal{O}_L$. I cannot find such $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The distributive property states $(a,b)(c,d)=(ac,ad,bc,bd)$. So we compute

$$\begin{array}{ll} (2,1+\sqrt{-5})^2 & =(4,2+2\sqrt{-5},-4+2\sqrt{-5}) \\ & =(2)(2,1+\sqrt{-5},-2+\sqrt{-5}) \\ & = (2)(2,3,-2+\sqrt{-5}) \\ & = (2)(1)=(2). \end{array}$$

by $3=(1+\sqrt{-5})-(-2+\sqrt{-5})$, valid since $(a,b)=(a-b,b)$. Thus $I^2=(\sqrt{2})^2$.

By unique factorization, $I^2=J^2\Leftrightarrow\, I=J$ in any Dedekind domain, e.g. number rings.

Answer (score 1):

These ideals are not equal. What is true is that $I^2=(\sqrt{2})$.

There are multiple ways of seeing this. One can compute that $\|(\sqrt{2})\|=2^4$ and $\|I\|=2^2$ which, since $2$ totally ramifies in $L$, gives the desired result.

Comment: I am not aware of the technology to follow your answer. Is there something wrong with mine?

Comment: @anon Nope, I just made a calculation error and thought that the square didn't obviously contain $2$. :)

Comment: The norm computation looks wrong. I think $\|(\sqrt{2})\| = |N_{L/\mathbb{Q}}(\sqrt{2})| = 4$.